# Gitlab Dependency Scan passing even though there are lots of vulnerabilities?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have added the template to the top of my gitlab.ci-yml

```
include:
  - template: Jobs/Dependency-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml
```

This is what the job looks like

```
dependency_scanning:
  stage: Install

gemnasium-dependency_scanning:
  extends:
    - .ds-analyzer
  variables:
    DS_MAX_DEPTH: -1
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID
  needs: []
  allow_failure: false
```

The problem i'm having is that, the job is passing even when there are vulnerabilities. How do I make the job fail when there are vulnerabilities

Ive tried to add allow_failure to be false but doesnt seem to be working still as the job passes.

Answer (score 0):

As it is written is the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/integrations/secure.html#exit-code):

> Following the POSIX exit code standard, the scanner exits with either 0 for success or 1 for failure. Success also includes the case when vulnerabilities are found.

Therefore, GitLab does not provide any option to fail a scanner job if any vulnerabilities are detected. One possible way to fail a job is to parse scanner's [output file](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/dependency_scanning/index.html#reports-json-format) inside `after_script` section or other job.